# React native sqlite storage not returning anything for android

Tags: react-native

> In react native application I am trying to use sqlite storage. I am
>   trying to execute  a simple query and trying to know the number of
>   rows
>
> **Code:-**

```
    var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
    var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'prabhuji.db',createFromLocation:1},openCB,errorCB)
const errorCB = (err) => {
    console.log("SQL Error: " + err);
  }
  const openCB = () => {
    console.log("Database OPENED");
  }
    class PredefinedLayout extends React.Component{
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
           this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent);
            this.props.navigator.setStyle({
                navBarTextColor: '#b4b0af'
            });
            db.transaction((tx)=>{
                alert(JSON.stringify(tx));
               tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM predefinedcart',[],(tx,results)=>{
                    var len = results.rows.length;
                    alert(len);
                })
            })
        }
    }
```

> I have created prabhuji.db in android/app/src/main/assets folder.

Also tried altering :-

```
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name:'prabhuji.db',createFromLocation:'~prabhuji.db'},openCB,errorCB)
```

But nothing showing. Can you please suggest me anything what I am doing wrong?